# PHP-FPM Status Page - request URI always /index.php

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I'm using nginx with `PHP-FPM`

My application requires all urls to be redirected to `index.php` (see nginx conf)

```
location / {
    root /var/www/app/public/
    try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
}


location ~ \.php$ {         
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

    set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

    fastcgi_index index.php;

    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```

To analyze some performance issues I wanted to use the fpm status page.
But the status page doesn't show me the real request URI

```
pid:                  1369
state:                Idle
start time:           03/Sep/2018:17:34:34 +0200
start since:          15
requests:             4
request duration:     29796
request method:       GET
request URI:          /index.php
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               /var/www/app/public/index.php
last request cpu:     67.12
last request memory:  6291456
```

So it's hard to tell which page is currently processed - is it maybe possible to add some additional info to fpm-status page or change the request URI?

Comment: Why have you removed the default line `include fastcgi_params;`? Put it back first.

Comment: I changed location so it only uses `include fastcgi_params` and `fastcgi_pass` but result is the same

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
 location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
     fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
     fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
     include fastcgi_params;
     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
     fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $http_host;
     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $request_uri;
 }
```

Ref: https://jolicode.com/blog/how-to-see-full-request-uri-in-fpm-status

Answer (score 1):

Still no answer, a bug was opened over 5 years ago on https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72319 with no reply.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a block its own block with a `fastcgi_index` set:

```
location ~ ^/_status$ {     
    include fastcgi_params
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;

    # the following is optional but nice to have
    # it will restrict access to the local monitoring system
    access_log off;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    allow ::1;
    deny all;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For my problem solution  was:

```
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO  $request_uri;
```